# JNI Get Context

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm using some example code for JNI.

I have a Java class,

```
public String getArtists(Context context)
...
```

However, the c++ interface to this, coded as below simply returns a null pointer

```
s_getArtistsGetArtistsMethodID = env->GetMethodID(s_getArtistsClassID, "getArtists", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V");
```

What am I missing here? The code below works as expected, so I assume it's to do with the context parameter.

```
s_getArtistsConstructorMethodID = env->GetMethodID(s_getArtistsClassID, "<init>", "()V");
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the ` "<init>"` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value is wrong.  V is void, you return a string.  Try:

```
env->GetMethodID(s_getArtistsClassID, "getArtists", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;"
```

Comment: There we go. Had no idea what those strings meant. Think I get it now. :P

Comment: Yes, it was making me wait to do it.

Comment: Where are you getting the `Context` here?